# An example of non-small object in Top, illustrated in Hovey's modelcategory textbook 49p

Tags: general-topology, model-categories

The below is the description in Hovey's textbook at 49p that the Sierpinski space is not small in the category Top.

"The Sierpinski space, consisting of two points where exactly one of them is open, is not small in Top, as was pointed out to the author by Stefan Schwede. To see this, given a limit ordinal $\lambda$, give the set $Y=$ $\lambda \cup\{\lambda\}$ the order topology. Let $X_\alpha$ be $Y \times\{0,1\}$ modulo the equivalence relation $(x, 0) \sim(x, 1)$ if $x<\alpha$. Then the $X_\alpha$ define a $\lambda$-sequence in Top. The colimit $X$ of the $X_\alpha$ is $Y$ with an extra point $(\lambda, 1)$ with exactly the same neighborhoods at $\lambda$. These two points define a continuous map from the Sierpinski space into $X$ which does not factor continuously through any $X_\alpha$."

It seems that the space $\{0,1\}$ is the Sierpinski space (not the discrete space). I can't figure out the last sentence: isn't the map $\{0,1\} \rightarrow X_0$ defined by $0 \mapsto (\lambda, 0)$ and $1\mapsto (\lambda,1)$ continuous since the unique open neighborhood of $0$ in the Sierpinski space is the whole space?

Thank you in advance for your helps!

Comment: You should explain what a small object is.

Answer (score 0):

This example is corrected in errata: https://people.math.rochester.edu/faculty/doug/otherpapers/hovey-model-cats-errata.pdf.